# Why doesn't my C code snippet work? Simplistic version does. Passing args without VA_ARGS for unsigned long long

Tags: c, stack, parameter-passing

Basically I'm writing a printf function for an dedicated system so I want to pass an optional number of arguments without using VA_ARGS macros. I knocked up a simple example and this block of code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int i, ...);
int main(int argc, char *argv);

int main(int argc, char *argv) {

    unsigned long long f = 6799000015ULL;
    unsigned long long *g;

    //g points to f
    g = &f;

    printf("natural: %llu in hex: %llX address: %x\n", *g, *g, g);

    //put pointer onto stack
    func(6, g, g);

    return 0;
}

void func(int i, ...) {

    unsigned long long *f;

    //pop value off
    f = *(&i + 1);

    printf("address: %x natural: %llu in hex: %llX\n", f, *f, *f);

}
```

However the larger example I'm trying to transfer this to *doesn't* work.

(in the main function):

```
unsigned long long f = 6799000015ULL;
unsigned long long *g;

g = &f;

kprintf("ull test: 1=%U 2=%X 3=%x 4= 5=\n", g, g, g);
```

(my dodgy printf function that I'm having trouble with. It maybe worth pointing out
this code DOES work with ints, char strings or anyother % flags which are passed by
*value* and not pointer. The only difference between what *did* work and the unsigned
long longs is one is bigger, so I pass by value instead to ensure I don't increment
the &format+ args part wrongly. Does that make sense?)

```
void kprintf(char *format, ...)
{
 char buffer[KPRINTF_BUFFER_SIZE];

 int bpos = 0; /* position to write to in buffer */
 int fpos = 0; /* position of char to print in format string */
 char ch; /* current character being processed*/

 /*
  * We have a variable number of paramters so we
  * have to increment from the position of the format
  * argument.
 */
 int arg_offset = 1;

 /*
  * Think this through Phill. &format = address of format on stack.
  * &(format + 1) = address of argument after format on stack.
  * void *p = &(format + arg_offset);
  * kprintf("xxx %i %s", 32, "hello");
  * memory would look like = [ 3, 32, 5, "xxx", 32, "hello" ]
  * get to 32 via p = &(format + 1); (int)p (because the int is copied, not a pointer)
  * get to hello via p = &(format + 2); (char*)p;
  */

 void *arg;
 unsigned long long *llu;
 arg = (void*) (&format + arg_offset);
 llu = (unsigned long long*) *(&format + arg_offset);

 while (1)
 {
  ch = format[fpos++];

  if (ch == '\0')
   break;

  if (ch != '%')
   buffer[bpos++] = ch;
  else
  {
   ch = format[fpos++];
   if (ch == 's')
    bpos += strcpy(&buffer[bpos], KPRINTF_BUFFER_SIZE - bpos, (char*)arg);
   else if (ch == '%')
    buffer[bpos++] = '%';
   else if (ch == 'i')
    bpos += int_to_str(&buffer[bpos], KPRINTF_BUFFER_SIZE - bpos, *((int*)arg));
   else if (ch == 'x')
    bpos += int_to_hex_str(&buffer[bpos], KPRINTF_BUFFER_SIZE - bpos, *((int*)arg));
   else if (ch == 'o')
    bpos += int_to_oct_str(&buffer[bpos], KPRINTF_BUFFER_SIZE - bpos, *((int*)arg));
   else if (ch == 'X') {
    //arg is expected to be a pointer we need to further dereference.
    bpos += unsigned_long_long_to_hex(&buffer[bpos], KPRINTF_BUFFER_SIZE - bpos, *llu);
   } else if (ch == 'U') {
    bpos += unsigned_long_long_to_str(&buffer[bpos], KPRINTF_BUFFER_SIZE - bpos, *llu);
   } else
   {
    puts("invalid char ");
    putch(ch);
    puts(" passed to kprintf\n");
   }

   arg_offset++;
   arg = (void *)(&format + arg_offset);
   llu = (unsigned long long*) *(&format + arg_offset);
  }
 }

 buffer[bpos] = '\0';
 puts(buffer);
}
```

(and the unsigned long long functions it goes on to call):

```
int unsigned_long_long_to_hex(char *buffer, int max_size, unsigned long long number)
{
 return ull_number_to_str(buffer, max_size, number, BASE_HEX);
}

int unsigned_long_long_to_str(char *buffer, int max_size, unsigned long long number) {
 return ull_number_to_str(buffer, max_size, number, BASE_DECIMAL);
}

int ull_number_to_str(char *buffer, int max_size, unsigned long long number, int base) {

 int bufpos = 0;

 unsigned int lo_byte = (unsigned int) number;
 unsigned int hi_byte = (unsigned int) (number >> 32);

 bufpos = number_to_str(buffer, max_size, lo_byte, base);
 bufpos += number_to_str(buffer + bufpos, max_size, hi_byte, base);

 return bufpos;

}

#define NUMERIC_BUFF_SIZE (11 * (ADDRESS_SIZE / 32))

int number_to_str(char *buffer, int max_size, int number, int base)
{
 char *char_map = "0123456789ABCDEF";

 int remain = 0;
 char buff_stack[NUMERIC_BUFF_SIZE];
 int stk_pnt = 0;
 int bpos = 0;

 /* with this method of parsing, the digits come out backwards */
 do 
 {
  if (stk_pnt > NUMERIC_BUFF_SIZE)
  {
   puts("Number has too many digits to be printed. Increasse NUMBERIC_BUFF_SIZE\n");
   return 0;
  }

  remain = number % base;
  number = number / base;
  buff_stack[stk_pnt++] = char_map[remain];
 } while (number > 0);

 /* before writing...ensure we have enough room */
 if (stk_pnt > max_size)
 {
  //error. do something?
  puts("number_to_str passed number with too many digits to go into buffer\n");
  //printf("error. stk_pnt > max_size (%d > %d)\n", stk_pnt, max_size);
  return 0;
 }

 /* reorder */
 while (stk_pnt > 0)
  buffer[bpos++] = buff_stack[--stk_pnt];

 return bpos;
}
```

Sorry guys, I can't see what I've done wrong. I appreciate this is a "wall of code" type scenario but hopefully someone can see what I've done wrong. I appreciate you probably dislike not using VA_ARGS but I don't understand why this technique shouldn't just work? And also, I'm linking with -nostdlib too. If someone can help I'd really appreciate it. Also, this isn't meant to be production quality code so if I lack some C fundamentals feel free to be constructive about it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad idea to code this way.  Use `stdarg.h`.

On the off chance (I presume this based on the name `kprintf`) that you're working on a hobby kernel or embedded project and looking to avoid using standard libraries, I recommend at least writing your own (architecture and compiler specific) set of stdarg macros that conform to the well-known interfaces and code against that.  That way your code doesn't look like such a WTF by dereferencing past the address of the last argument.

You can make a `va_list` type that stores the last-known address, and your `va_arg` macro could appropriately align the `sizeof` of the type it's passed and advance the pointer accordingly.  For most conventions I have worked on for x86, every type is promoted to 32 bits...

Comment: Note that the `va_*()` macros from `stdarg.h` are just that - macros.  They typically expand to inline code similar to what the OP is trying to write (only correct), and they do not require linking with any library.  For example, `stdarg.h` is usually one of the headers provided by GCC, rather than the system C library.

Comment: @caf I agree in principle, but when I was working on a hobby kernel I had some difficulty with that approach.  The standard headers might depend on other headers and that might conflict with what you're trying to do.  It's often simpler (or at least less of a headache) to write your own.

Comment: That's probably true in general, but `stdarg.h` is a bit of a special case - as one of the freestanding headers (along with `float.h`, `iso646.h`, `limits.h`, `stdbool.h`, `stddef.h` and `stdint.h`), it should not drag in anything untoward, and should be safe to use in a kernel environment.

Answer (score 2):

You have to read on the [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) for your platform, i.e. how on your target processor/OS function arguments are passed, and how registers are saved. Not all parameters are passed on stack. Depending on number of parameters and their types, many complex situations can arise.

Comment: I'm using x86 and there is no underlying operating system. I'm using gcc and my compiler. What your link says to me is that it may use registers. So popping from the stack (when the args are in the registers) would presumably retrieve the wrong value. If this is true, can you recommend a work around to what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Is there anyway to isolate that as the true cause (as opposed to just a logical error above on my part? Is what you're describing along the lines of an optimiser inlining the code so it doesn't result in stack modification?

Comment: I wonder how I could say it better: follow the calling conventions of your target. Odds are that they're much more complicated that what you've coded above.

Answer (score 2):

I should add: if you want to manipulate the stack by hand as you are doing above, you need to do it in **assembler**, not in C. The C language follows a defined standard, and what you are doing above it not legal code (i.e., its meaning is not well-defined). As such, the compiler is allowed to do anything it wants with it, such as optimize it in weird ways unsuitable to your needs.